# Illustrator workflow: merge vertexes on contact

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

When drawing a path B with the pen tool, is there a way to automatically merge with another path A, when I’m adding a vertex on path B that is at the same position as path A?

Comment: Hi gordie, could you add an example image with the process please? The pen tool allows automatically connection between end and starting points, it's not easy to understand your problem with this explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the pen tool you can click an end point to join it to any path you are currently drawing. If your vertex ends in an anchor point, simply clicking that anchor point while drawing with the pen tool will connect it to the active path.

If you have two separate, disjointed, path segments you can use `Object > Path > Join` to join *open* anchor points of separate paths. Whether or not this is easier than clicking an anchor with the pen tool is dependent upon the artwork itself.

If, by chance, you are seeking to join a path to the **middle** of another path, that is *not* possible. All anchor points have an *in* and an *out*. You can only ever have two path segments connected to any anchor point. And at no time can you connect a path to the *middle* of another path segment or connect three path segments to the same anchor point.

In all respects, there is absolutely no "automatic merging" of paths or points in Illustrator. The only existing options with such merging is by using tools such as the Blob Brush, but there's nothing with relation to *paths*.